# Facebook PHP skd getLoginUrl redirection

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Im using Facebook PHP SDK v5.
For login funcitonality im using "getLoginUrl" funciton which return the facebook login url. It works fine on desktop and mobiles , however on mobiles I would prefer to get the link to the Facebook mobile application rather than website URL. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the first parameter of `getLoginUrl()` to pass a redirect URI that point to your mobile URL.